# How to write overload operators for STL containers and alogrithm functions?

Tags: c++

For example, I want to write overload functions for `set_difference` which compares the type `std::set<point>`

```
class myIter : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int> {
public:
    myIter(int n) : num(n){}
    myIter(const myIter & n) : num(n.num){}
    int & operator *(){return num;}
    myIter & operator ++(){++num; return *this;}
    bool operator !=(const myIter & n){return n.num != num;}
private:
    int num;
};

struct point
{
  point(int X, int Y):x(X), y(Y){}
  int x;
  int y;
}

int main()
{
   set <point> myset;
   myset.insert(point(1, 1);
   myset.insert(point(3, 2);
   myset.insert(point(5, 3);

  //find the missing elements in set for `point.x` using `set_difference`

   std::set<int> missing;

   std::set_difference(myIter(myset.begin()->x+1), myIter(myset.rbegin()->x),
   myset.begin(), myset.end(), std::insert_iterator<std::set<int>>(missing, missing.begin()));

}
```

After applying the `std::set_difference` on `point.x` variables the `set<int> missing` must be:

```
missing[0] {2}
missing[1] {4}
```

How do i know how to write the overload operators for the operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `std::set<point>` requires that `point` is less-than-comparable. You can either define `operator<` for `point`, or provide a separate function object that does the comparison as the second template parameter `std::set<point,MyCompare>`.

Once you actually have your elements in the set, you can use `set_difference`. It's worth noting that `set_difference` doesn't actually require you to use `std::set` for your input --- you could just use a vector and thus avoid having to provide the comparison function.

To use `set_difference`, you will need to ensure that the `value_type`s of the two iterator ranges are the same, so you'll need another iterator wrapper that returns just the `x` portion of the `point` values for the second range.

```
std::set_difference(myIter(myset.begin()->x+1), myIter(myset.rbegin()->x),
    extractXIter(myset.begin()), extractXIter(myset.end()),
    std::insert_iterator<std::set<int>>(missing, missing.begin()));
```

Answer (score 1):

(My second attempt at the answer.)

This is rather an elaboration of Anthony Williams's answer.

Both iterators that you need are available in the Boost libraries (your own myIter is lacking functionality which may make your code uncompilable with other compilers).

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/mem_fn.hpp>

struct point
{
  point(int X, int Y):x(X), y(Y){}
  int x;
  int y;
};

bool operator< (const point& a, const point& b)
{
    return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y);
}

int main()
{
   std::set <point> myset;
   myset.insert(point(1, 1));
   myset.insert(point(3, 2));
   myset.insert(point(5, 3));

  //find the missing elements in set for `point.x` using `set_difference`
   std::set<int> missing;
   using namespace boost;
   std::set_difference(
    counting_iterator<int>(myset.begin()->x+1), counting_iterator<int>(myset.rbegin()->x),
    make_transform_iterator( myset.begin(), mem_fn(&point::x)),
    make_transform_iterator( myset.end(), mem_fn(&point::x)),
    std::inserter(missing, missing.begin()));
   std::copy(missing.begin(), missing.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Points of interest:

- `point` needs to be "less-than" comparable, if you want to store them in a `set`
- `boost::counting_iterator` is a better `myIter`
- `boost::transform_iterator` allows you to apply a function to the value when dereferenced. In combination with `boost::mem_fn` it obtains the `Point::x` member when the iterator is dereferenced.
- use the helper function `std::inserter` to get the template arguments deduced
- the results don't have to be stored in a `set` (neither does the input have to come from a `set`, as long as the range is sorted with respect to the used predicate - here comparing the x member.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are after implementing `operator<()` for your type, because it is used by several types and algorithms of the standard library:

```
struct point
{
  point(int X, int Y):x(X), y(Y){}
  int x;
  int y;
};

inline bool operator<(const point& lhs, const point& rhs)
{
  if( lhs.x < rhs.x ) return true;
  if( lhs.x > rhs.x ) return false;
  return lhs.y < rhs.y;
}
```

That's a quite naive way of judging which point is "smaller". You might want to improve on the algorithm, but the syntactical mechanics stay the same.

---

Note that, once you have defined `p1 < p2`, users of your type usually expect `p1 > p2` (and `p1 <= p2` etc.) to work as well. Since this is trivial, it doesn't hurt to provide the rest of the comparison operators:

```
inline bool operator> (const point& lhs, const point& rhs) {return rhs < lhs;}
inline bool operator<=(const point& lhs, const point& rhs) {return !(lhs > rhs);}
inline bool operator>=(const point& lhs, const point& rhs) {return !(lhs < rhs);}
inline bool operator==(const point& lhs, const point& rhs)
{
  return lhs.x < rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y;
}
inline bool operator!=(const point& lhs, const point& rhs) {return !(lhs==rhs);}
```

Comment: Note the use of `Boost.Operators` to seamlessly define those "completary operators" automatically :)

Comment: @Matthieu: I have been counting on you to appear and suggest that. `:)` (I haven't had the chance to do much C++ in a year now, so I never got around trying this out, and I'm uncomfortable with suggesting something I haven't done myself and don't know how to do. So feel free to keep pointing it out whenever I write them all by hand.)

Comment: my pleasure :) it's more syntactic sugar to avoid writing boilerplate code than anything "functional", but it helps keeping the code tidy.